# post request to php script

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, post

I'm trying to make a post request to a php file after a user disconnects from the node server.

The node server is SSL certified as well as where the php script is hosted.

```
function updateRank(user, rank) {
  var form = {
    user: user,
    rank: rank
  };

  var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
  var contentLength = formData.length;

  request({
    headers: {
      'Content-Length': contentLength,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'accept': '*/*',
      'user-agent':'*'
    },
    uri: 'https://wtf.com/pechp/updateUser.php',
    body: formData,
    method: 'POST'
  }, function (err, res, body) {
    //it works!
  });
}
```

I keep getting a 500 error when I make the request. THE problem is not with the code. It has something to do with the headers. I'm not sure what though.

This is the response I get when running locally:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
localhost/:1 Failed to load https://wtf.com/pechp/updateUser.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Here is my php file:

```
    <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');

    // Create connection
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    if ($connection) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['user']);
        $newRank = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['rank']);
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE wtf SET rank = '$newRank' WHERE username = '$username'");

        if 

($result) {
       echo "success"
    } else {
       echo "fail";
    }
} else {
    echo "connection failed";
}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Can you compare headers for this request and  a working one?  If you don't control the PHP server you could set up a fake page on another server that just echoes the headers and content and send to that.

Comment: Have you checked the server's logs?  it shoulds help you to see the error message

Comment: Posted the error when running locally

Comment: The error says it all. You can't make an ajax request to this domain from your website.

Comment: That's not so clear cut. 

I can make other http post requests from my website but not from the node server? Not understanding that.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Nov  Does your PHP server have  the same domaine as your client ?  Have tried using another client like postMan?

Comment: Are you using reactjs/angular in the front-end. which of them?

Comment: An inelegant but effective way to find the error is to put a die(‘ok to here’); as the first line of code. Then start moving it down until you get the 500 server error...